# MySQL - Storing numbers, greater than 1, with a large number of decimal places

Tags: mysql, floating-point, decimal

I need to use an accurate number that has many decimal places. If I use the type `decimal` (because float is not precise enough to store such numbers) I can have something like `0.003352466` and it is preserved accurately. However if I make that number larger than 1, I cannot do it `1.003352466` will fail to be stored.

How do I store both types of numbers in one column?

Like, if one row has the value `0.003352466` but the next row needs to store `1.003352466`, how do I do this? I have not been able to figure this out.

FYI I had initially tried DECIMAL(10,10) and that suffered the same failure as mentioned above.

---

EDIT:

I have tried specifying `DECIMAL(2,10)` but that fails as the number on the left must be equal to or greater than that on the right. SO I tried `DECIMAL(10,10)` and that simply fails to write to the database. As I mentioned above it WILL let me enter `0.003352466` but not `1.003352466`

Solution... make the first number larger than the second and it works!

`DECIMAL(10,10)` will fail to write as mentioned but `DECIMAL(10,9)` will succeed. Go figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a wrong table definition (care to show it?). From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html):

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL
>   column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of
>   values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1
>   are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the
>   precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.
>   (Older versions of MySQL permitted a
>   range of 1 to 254.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right
>   of the decimal point (the scale). It
>   has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no
>   larger than M.

So, a `DECIMAL(11,9)` would work in this case, alter as required.

Comment: Hey! I tried DECIMAL(10,10) and it would not let me write a number greater than 1 (0.23343 worked but 1.23343 failed to write) however when I did DECIMAL(10,9) it worked! No idea why, though.

Comment: Arrueh... In the DECIMAL definition, the 1st number says how many digits (what precision) you want left & right of the decimal seperator _combined_. The 2nd number tells how many you want on the right of the decimal seperator _of that previous number_. If you set `10,10`, there's no room for numbers > 1 anymore. So, the 1st number always needs to be bigger than the 2nd number, and the 2nd number minus the 1st is how many places you can have _before_ the decimal seperator.

Answer (score 2):

Provide the precision to your field's declaration.

`DECIMAL(N, M)` means "`N` digits total, with `M` decimal places".

Say, `DECIMAL(10, 2)` will allow you to store numbers from `0.00` to `±99999999.99`.

Comment: The problem is that I need it to be something like DECIMAL(2,10) (in my example I showed 9 places to the right) but the number on the left must be => the one on the right. I need 10 digits to the right so I tried DECIMAL(10,10) but that still fails to write to the database.

Comment: @gaoshan88: what we're stating is that the number on the left needs to be _bigger_ than the one on the right in the `DECIMAL()` definition. You can then use (N-M) number of digits on the left that way.

Comment: I see.. I just figured that out after seeing how you wrote it in your example. Thanks guys.